# Disable "save" prompt in SQL Server Management Studio 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

I just want to close all my query windows without saving, but SSMS always prompts me and I can't find the turn-off switch. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a more recent answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an off switch - currently!

Microsoft are reluctant to add one, but you can perhaps join the growing throng of people who are trying to persuade them:

[prompting-for-modified-windows-when-closing-ssms-should-be-optional](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124686/prompting-for-modified-windows-when-closing-ssms-should-be-optional)

Comment: Maybe I'll just wire up an Autohotkey to Control-F4 that sends an N if the window prompts. Could probably automate that across all open tabs. Feh.

Comment: @Caveatrob Download [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) then use `pskill ssms`. (NB - To avoid confusion - Not the same Martin as the answerer here!)

Answer (score 26):

In `SQL Server Management Studio 2016` you can unchecked the `Prompt to save unsaved T-SQL query windows on close`:

[image]

The option is under the `Query Execution\SQL Server\General` sub-menu.

Once unchecked, the annoying prompt for saving is disabled.

Comment: In menu bar: Tools\Options\Query Execution\SQL Server\General

Answer (score 3):

The feature doesn't exist, but you can vote for it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124686/prompting-for-modified-windows-when-closing-ssms-should-be-optional).